# Opportunity Stage cannot be changed backwards :-

Tags: validation-rule

I have created a VR where I want the users to not change the Stage backwards. However, The system admins can change the opportunity to back stages. Here is my code and it is not working as it should be :-

```
OR
(AND
(ISCHANGED(StageName),
ISPICKVAL(PRIORVALUE(StageName), "0. Prospecting"),
Intro_Meeting_Accepted__c = FALSE),
(AND
(ISCHANGED(StageName),
ISPICKVAL(PRIORVALUE(StageName), "1. Presentation"),
Sales_Process_Document_Part_A_B__c = FALSE)),
(AND(
ISCHANGED(StageName),
ISPICKVAL(PRIORVALUE(StageName), "2. Scoping"),
Sales_Process_Doc_Part_C__c = FALSE)),
(AND(
ISCHANGED(StageName),
ISPICKVAL(PRIORVALUE(StageName), "3. Proposal"),
SOW_MSA__c = FALSE)),
(AND(
ISCHANGED(StageName),
ISPICKVAL(PRIORVALUE(StageName), "4. Closing"),
PO_has_been_received__c = FALSE))
)&&
NOT(ISPICKVAL(StageName, "Closed Lost"))&&
NOT($Profile.Name <> "System Administrator")
```

Comment: Please always include a specific description of the behavior that is not as desired in your posts. We cannot tell just by looking at your metadata. Here, I think you'll probably see the solution if you look carefully at the last line of your Validation Rule. There are lots of existing posts on SFSE about how to exclude users and profiles from Validation Rules; please do search for existing questions as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ISCHANGED(StageName) &&
CASE(StageName,
"Direct Bill Process", 1,
"Awaiting Reservation", 2,
"Reservation Process", 3,
"Awaiting Move In", 4,
"Checked In", 5,
"Checked Out", 6,
"Closed Won", 7,
"Closed Lost", 7,
0)
<
CASE(PRIORVALUE(StageName), 
"Direct Bill Process", 1, 
"Awaiting Reservation", 2, 
"Reservation Process", 3,
"Awaiting Move In", 4,
"Checked In", 5,
"Checked Out", 6,
"Closed Won", 7,
"Closed Lost", 7,
0)
&& $Profile.Name = "System Administrator"

source: https://success.salesforce.com/answers?id=90630000000gt6nAAA

Comment: Hey Amber, would you mind [edit]ing to include the substantive content of the solution here? We try to avoid having key content behind links.

Comment: done! thanks and sorry! :-)

Comment: Thanks @AmberNeillBoaz,
I tried doing same earlier as well, but non sys admin users can also change the stage backwards, i logged in as Non-Sys admin user in my sandbox to check that if it works. Here is my VR code :-

SCHANGED(StageName) &&
CASE(StageName,
"Prospecting", 0,
"Presentation", 1,
"Scoping", 2,
"Proposal", 3,
"Closing", 4,
"Closed Won", 5,
"Closed Lost", 5,
0)
<
CASE(PRIORVALUE(StageName),
"Prospecting", 0,
"Presentation", 1,
"Scoping", 2,
"Proposal", 3,
"Closing", 4,
"Closed Won", 5,
"Closed Lost", 5,
0)
&& $Profile.Name = "System Administrator"